# Trade badges for points

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, badges

I looked for this topic and got no results, so I am asking the obvious:

Could users trade points for badges?

For instance:

- 100 points for a bronze badge,
- 250 for a silver badge,
- 500 for a gold badge

Comment: *"you receive badges for being especially helpful"* i feel the "helpful" aspect of them would be lost if you could just buy them. plus they wont really mean anything unlike badges you get for reviewing or asking well received questions

Comment: No. What is the benefit you see in this? Feature requests aren't just 'do it cause' you need to have a problem you intend this to fix.  Anyway, I am not sure if  you mean buy badges, or sell badges...

Comment: Please read the [tag wiki for `feature-request`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info). A key sentence: "Basically, prove to the administration that they should spend time developing your feature."

Comment: If you have a gold badge or two, chances are *very good* that your reputation's pretty high.  Bronze badges are introductory anyway.

Comment: I was just interested in selling badges. But I spose if you earn them you should just accept them as they are.

Comment: But again, what is the benefit in selling badges? Seriously. You get rep from upvotes on a Q. You get enough upvotes, you get the 'nice Q' badge. You then can get MORE rep by selling the badge? Are you just trying to find other ways to get rep?

Comment: Technically, I am looking for an easier way to get reputation points so I can get more privileges. My line of work in Basic is not getting me very far.

Comment: An *easy* way is suggesting good edits. So far you only did 7. Each approved suggested edit earns you 2 points to a maximum of 1000.

Comment: @Makoto I have _three_ gold badges, but my rep is still below 2k...

Comment: Ooh, that would get me up to almost 4 million rep. Um, no.

Comment: @JonSkeet it would be more fun for you to spend your rep on buying badges - more chance of breaking the UI :)

Comment: @JonSkeet that was your plan all along. You will start selling them for bitcoins once they will allow us to share them

Comment: OMG! The Ghod of all-time posts has responded to one of my posts! I am forever blessed!

Answer (score 14):

This isn't a good idea since that feature could easily be abused.

For example, an easy (and dishonest) way of earning a lot of reputation quickly with that feature would be to create a sock puppet, fill out the sock puppet's "about me" and read the tour while connected to the sock puppet's account. Then the sock puppet would earn two bronze badges (Autobiographer and Informed) and trade them for 200 reputation immediately.

The sock puppet could then upvote a few of your posts (not too many to avoid their votes getting reversed) and then use bounties to give away the 200 reputation to your main account.

And it would be even worse when the survey is available, because then you could take the survey with your sock puppet and earn the Census badge, which would be worth 250 reputation.

Also note that giving away the reputation as a bounty would give the sock puppet the Altruist and Investor badges, which they could trade for another 200 reputation which they could give to your main account.

If a new user did this just 10 times, it would be enough to get them enough reputation to vote to close, without having done anything to contribute to the site. And a determined user could easily use this to unlock almost any privilege they want.

Also, while they're at it, the sock puppets could favorite all of your questions to earn you a lot of Favorite Question and Stellar Question badges, which you then could trade for reputation. How much reputation you would get from this depends on how many questions you have, but if I created 100 sock puppets that each favorited all my questions, I would earn 46 500 reputation.

Besides, it's relatively easy to abuse the system to get badges. Right now it's not such a big deal since badges aren't really worth anything (even though robo-reviewers are causing problems in the review queues for the badges), but if you could trade badges for reputation, a lot of people would abuse the system to get badges.

One of the most well-known way to abuse the system for badges is robo-reviewing. Robo-reviewing is already a big problem, but if badges were worth reputation, a lot more people would be doing it. This would result in a disaster for the review queues, and a lot of users would get thousands of extra reputation points that they don't deserve from robo-reviewing.

It's also possible to abuse the system to get other badges. A user could share a link, and then use proxies or public wifi to visit that link with other IP addresses and earn the Announcer badge. They could create a useless tag and edit into 50 questions to earn the Taxonomist badge. I've never heard of any of these being a problem (probably because they're too much effort for too little benefit), but if badges were worth reputation, people would probably do that.

Not to mention that the first time you award a 50 reputation bounty, you will actually earn 150 reputation for that (200 reputation for two bronze badges minus the 50 reputation you gave away), which goes against the purpose of a bounty.

I'm sure there would also be a lot of other ways to abuse that feature, but I think you got the point. The feature you're suggesting would be way to easy too abuse, so it's not a good idea.

Comment: Not to mention that if, once sold, a badge can be re-obtained, then the effect would only be magnified.... wow. I think we found a change that would completely break stack.

Comment: I didn't want to break anything, I just thought barter was the core to all systems.